# Falling down conditional if

Tags: c#

Hi how do I make my if statement more efficient? Basically what I would like to do is to check if a "hand" in poker is "straight" I would like to check if player has a "straight","flush" and above. Example: if the game hand is flush, I don't need to check for straight and just check for "flush" and above.

```
public enum HandType
{
    Single = 1,
    Pair = 2,
    Triple = 3,
    Straight = 4,
    Flush = 5,
    FullHouse = 6,
    FourOfAKind = 7,
    StraightFlush = 8,
}

public List<CardData> GetBotHands(List<CardData> gameHand)
{
    List<CardData> playerHand = new List<CardData>();

    HandType handType = HandEvaluator.EvaluateHand(gameHand);

    if(handType < HandType.Straight)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if(handType == HandType.Straight)
    {
        playerHand = GetStraight(gameHand);
        if(playerHand != null)
        {
            return playerHand;
        }

        playerHand = GetFlush(gameHand);
        if (playerHand != null)
        {
            return playerHand;
        }

        playerHand = GetFullHouse(gameHand);
        if (playerHand != null)
        {
            return playerHand;
        }

        playerHand = GetFourKind(gameHand);
        if (playerHand != null)
        {
            return playerHand;
        }

        playerHand = GetStraightFlush(gameHand);
        if (playerHand != null)
        {
            return playerHand;
        }
    }
    else if(handType == HandType.Flush)
    {
        playerHand = GetFlush(gameHand);
        if (playerHand != null)
        {
            return playerHand;
        }

        playerHand = GetFullHouse(gameHand);
        if (playerHand != null)
        {
            return playerHand;
        }

        playerHand = GetFourKind(gameHand);
        if (playerHand != null)
        {
            return playerHand;
        }

        playerHand = GetStraightFlush(gameHand);
        if (playerHand != null)
        {
            return playerHand;
        }
    }
    else if(handType == HandType.FullHouse)
    ...

    return null;
}
```

By following solution from @Shiran Dror , now I have this code. But is there a way to make it shorter?

```
if(handType == HandType.Straight)
{
    return GetStraight(gameHand) ?? GetFlush(gameHand) ?? GetFullHouse(gameHand) ?? GetFourKind(gameHand) ?? GetStraightFlush(gameHand);
}
else if(handType == HandType.Flush)
{
    return GetFlush(gameHand) ?? GetFullHouse(gameHand) ?? GetFourKind(gameHand) ?? GetStraightFlush(gameHand);
}
else if(handType == HandType.FullHouse)
...
```

Comment: If you don't need to check for Straight if hand is Flush, why don't you *start* by checking for a Flush?

Comment: I did. I want to know how can I make the code more efficient, probably by using the enum values and the > operator. I just can't think of a way to do it since I'm kinda new.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ?? like this:

```
return GetStraight(gameHand) ?? GetFlush(gameHand) ... ?? GetStraightFlush(gameHand);
```

it will return the first none null value

### EDIT - getting it shorter

```
switch (handType) {
  case HandType.Straight:
    return GetStraight(gameHand) ?? GetFlush(gameHand) ... ?? GetStraightFlush(gameHand);

  case HandType.Flush:
    return GetStraight(gameHand) ?? GetFlush(gameHand) ... ?? GetStraightFlush(gameHand);
...
  default: 
    return null;
}
```

also if you call on the same function again and again you can add a new function so you won't repeat the code. Example:

```
private HandType RepetitiveCheck(gameHand) 
{
  return GetFlush(gameHand) ?? GetFullHouse(gameHand) ?? GetFourKind(gameHand) ?? GetStraightFlush(gameHand)
}
```

and in the main function use it like this

```
switch (handType) {
  case HandType.Straight:
    return GetStraight(gameHand) ?? RepetitiveCheck(gameHand);

  case HandType.Flush:
    return RepetitiveCheck(gameHand);
...
  default: 
    return null;
}
```

Comment: if it is null, I would like it to continue to check for flush, full house and above

Comment: @Profitzky that's exactly what `??` does - it's a null-coalesce operator - if a value expression is `null` it continues to the next

Comment: If it's not too much to ask is there a way to make the code even shorter?

if(handType == HandType.Straight)
{
    return GetStraight(gameHand) ?? GetFlush(gameHand) ?? GetFullHouse(gameHand) ?? GetFourKind(gameHand) ?? GetStraightFlush(gameHand);
}
else if(handType == HandType.Flush)
{
    return GetFlush(gameHand) ?? GetFullHouse(gameHand) ?? GetFourKind(gameHand) ?? GetStraightFlush(gameHand);
}
else if(handType == HandType.FullHouse)
...